# Assist me in translating Visual Basic regex to C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I paid for the following piece of code but my coder coded it in Visual Basic. I tried using an online converter but none of them convert it properly.

Do you guys mind helping me convert the following piece of code to C#? Thanks:

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<input name=""authenticity_token"" type=""hidden"" value="".*"" />")
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(theusercp)
        For Each itemcode As Match In matches
            autcode = UrlEncode((itemcode.Value.Split("""").GetValue(5)))
        Next
```

Comment: I think you just learned to write better specifications.

Comment: Telerik code converter worked fine for me http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @PhilBolduc I keep getting this error though:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Comment: Someone down-voted all the four answers. Down-voter, please explain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work properly for you?

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\".*\" />");
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(theusercp);
foreach (Match itemcode in matches) {
    autcode = UrlEncode((itemcode.Value.Split('\"').GetValue(5)));
}
```

Perhaps you'll also have to write `var autcode` and/or `Server.UrlEncode`.

Comment: It works except I get an error with UrlEncode

Comment: Its says Server.UrlEncode and UrlEncode do not exist in the current context

Comment: How about `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`?

Comment: Nope same error, I even tried: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode and it gave me another error

Comment: Everything works, now I just need to fix the UrlEncode error

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't determine from your code snippet what type/namespace does the `UrlEncode` function belong to. To find that out, it might be helpful to look at the whole VB file.

Comment: By the way, in order to use System.Web.HttpUtility, you need to add a reference to System.Web assembly in your C# project.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` accepts a string, so the parameter passed to the method cannot be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this (must admit I didn't try to compile or test)

```
var r = New Regex("<input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\".*\" />");
var matches = r.Matches(theusercp);
foreach (var itemcode in matches){
  var autcode = Server.UrlEncode(itemcode.Value.Split("\"")[5]);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful not to tell what the reason for the downvote is.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little inherently "VB" about this code; it just uses the .NET RegEx class. I'm not sure what online translators you're talking about but this translates almost directly into C#:

```
var r = new Regex("<input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\".*\" />");
var matches = r.Matches(theusercp);
foreach (var itemcode in matches)
{
  autcode = UrlEncode(itemcode.Value.Split("\"").GetValue(5));
}
```

I hope this isn't all of the code, however, since it doesn't actually *do* anything with the matched tokens in your regex (and makes pretty poor use of regex matching to boot.)

```
var r = new Regex("<input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"(.*)\" />");
foreach (var match in r.Matches(theusercp))
{
  autcode = UrlEncode(match.Group[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: The second code portion is the correct one correct? Or the first one?

Comment: The two code portions do the same thing; the first one is a direct translation of the VB, while the second one IMO is more efficient. Neither of them actually does anything with the data matched by the regex, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities to escape the double-quotes in c#. Either by using a backslash to escape it `\"` or by using a verbatim string and using two double quotes `""`

```
string s = "double quote (\")";
```

or

```
string s = @"double quote ("")";
```

Verbatim strings introduced with `@` do not interprete the backslash as escape character and can span several lines

```
string s = @"Hello
 World";
```

Your code would look like this in C#

```
var r = new Regex(@"<input name=""authenticity_token"" type=""hidden"" value="".*"" />");
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(theusercp);
foreach (Match itemcode in matches) {
    autcode = UrlEncode(itemcode.Value.Split("\"")[5]);
}
```